# Is there a single valued definition for $\sqrt[n]{z}$ on $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Since the $n$th root of a complex number has $n$ possibilities, which one do you choose so that its restriction to $\Bbb{R}$ is the positive square root if $r$ is positive and $\sqrt{|r|}i$ if $r$ is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$\sqrt[n]{r e^{i\theta}} = \sqrt[n]{r} e^{i\frac{\theta}{n}}
$$
where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$

Seems to do the trick.